# DScintilla, code folding not working for me

Tags: delphi, folding, scintilla

I have this code, to initialize Scintilla with xml lexer:

```
procedure TfrmWeMain.DScintilla1MarginClick(ASender: TObject; AModifiers,
  APosition, AMargin: Integer);
  var line_number:integer;
begin

  line_number:= (ASender as TDScintilla).SendEditor(SCI_LINEFROMPOSITION, APosition, 0);

  case AMargin of
     1:
    begin
      (ASender as TDScintilla).SendEditor(SCI_TOGGLEFOLD, line_number, 0);
    end

  end;
end;

procedure TfrmWeMain.addDocument(filename:string);
var frmEditor:tFrameEditor;
ts:TTabSheet;
procedure setColors(lang:integer;fore:integer;const back:tcolor=clWindow; 
    const bold:boolean=false; const italic:boolean=false; 
    const underline:boolean=false; const font:string='Courier New'; 
    const size:integer=10);

begin
  frmEditor.sci.StyleSetBack(lang,colortorgb(back));
  frmEditor.sci.StyleSetFore(lang,colortorgb(fore));
  frmEditor.sci.StyleSetFont(lang,font);
  frmEditor.sci.StyleSetBold(lang,bold);
  frmEditor.sci.StyleSetItalic(lang,italic);
  frmEditor.sci.StyleSetUnderline(lang,underline);
  frmEditor.sci.StyleSetSize(lang,size);
end;

procedure setFolding;
begin
  frmEditor.sci.SetMarginTypeN(1,0);
  frmEditor.sci.SetMarginTypeN(1,SC_MARGIN_SYMBOL);
  frmEditor.sci.SetMarginMaskN(1,SC_MASK_FOLDERS);
  frmEditor.sci.SetMarginWidthN(0,40);
  frmEditor.sci.SetMarginWidthN(1,20);
  frmEditor.sci.SendEditor(SCI_MARKERDEFINE, SC_MARKNUM_FOLDER, SC_MARK_PLUS);
  frmEditor.sci.SendEditor(SCI_MARKERDEFINE, SC_MARKNUM_FOLDEROPEN, SC_MARK_MINUS);
  frmEditor.sci.SendEditor(SCI_MARKERDEFINE, SC_MARKNUM_FOLDEREND, SC_MARK_EMPTY);
  frmEditor.sci.SendEditor(SCI_MARKERDEFINE, SC_MARKNUM_FOLDERMIDTAIL, SC_MARK_EMPTY);
  frmEditor.sci.SendEditor(SCI_MARKERDEFINE, SC_MARKNUM_FOLDEROPENMID, SC_MARK_EMPTY);
  frmEditor.sci.SendEditor(SCI_MARKERDEFINE, SC_MARKNUM_FOLDERSUB, SC_MARK_EMPTY);
  frmEditor.sci.SendEditor(SCI_MARKERDEFINE, SC_MARKNUM_FOLDERTAIL, SC_MARK_EMPTY);
  frmEditor.sci.SendEditor(SCI_SETFOLDFLAGS, 16, 0); // 16      Draw line below if not expanded
  frmEditor.sci.OnMarginClick:=DScintilla1MarginClick;
  frmeditor.sci.StartStyling(0,0);
end;
begin

///...
 frmEditor.sci.SetLexer(SCLEX_XML);
 frmEditor.sci.SetCodePage(CP_UTF8);
 setColors(SCE_H_DEFAULT,clBlack);
 setColors(SCE_H_TAG,clPurple,clWindow,true);
 setColors(SCE_H_TAGUNKNOWN,clRed);
 setColors(SCE_H_ATTRIBUTE,clNavy);
 setColors(SCE_H_ATTRIBUTEUNKNOWN,clRed);
 setColors(SCE_H_NUMBER,clBlue);
 setColors(SCE_H_DOUBLESTRING,clBlue);
 setColors(SCE_H_SINGLESTRING,clBlue);
 setColors(SCE_H_OTHER,clBlack);
 setColors(SCE_H_COMMENT,clTeal);
 setColors(SCE_H_ENTITY,clPurple);
 setColors(SCE_H_TAGEND,clPurple);
 setColors(SCE_H_CDATA,clTeal);
 setFolding;

 ///...


end;
```

See the setFolding part of the code, it's that where the folding should get in motion, but it doesn't. I can't see the fold markers, neither the folding itself works.

I need to know what i am missing here, or what i am doing wrong. Code snippets in Delphi, C++, C# or pseudocode are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have the folding example for XML. You were quite close to get it to work, but you missed to set 2 important details, enable folding globally and for your language (see [here](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html) for fold.html folding property for XML) and after that enable fold margin to be sensitive for mouse clicks, what actually enables the OnMarginClick event to be fired (see [here](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_SETMARGINSENSITIVEN)).
For this example I've avoided to use the SendEditor messaging and used the full power of the DScintilla wrapper.

```
uses
  DScintillaTypes;

const
  MARGIN_LINE_NUMBERS = 0;
  MARGIN_CODE_FOLDING = 1;

procedure TForm1.DScintilla1MarginClick(ASender: TObject; AModifiers,
  APosition, AMargin: Integer);
var
  Line: Integer;
begin
  Line := DScintilla1.LineFromPosition(APosition);

  if AMargin = MARGIN_CODE_FOLDING then
    DScintilla1.ToggleFold(Line);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

  procedure SetColors(const Style: Integer; const Fore: Integer;
    const Back: TColor = clWindow; const Bold: Boolean = False;
    const Italic: Boolean = False; const Underline: Boolean = False;
    const Font: string = 'Courier New'; const Size: Integer = 10);
  begin
    DScintilla1.StyleSetBack(Style, ColorToRGB(Back));
    DScintilla1.StyleSetFore(Style, ColorToRGB(Fore));
    DScintilla1.StyleSetFont(Style, Font);
    DScintilla1.StyleSetSize(Style, Size);
    DScintilla1.StyleSetBold(Style, Bold);
    DScintilla1.StyleSetItalic(Style, Italic);
    DScintilla1.StyleSetUnderline(Style, Underline);
  end;

begin
  DScintilla1.SetLexer(SCLEX_XML);
  DScintilla1.SetCodePage(CP_UTF8);

  // this is very important and enables the folding globally
  // and then the language specific, see [1] for details

  DScintilla1.SetProperty('fold', '1');
  DScintilla1.SetProperty('fold.html', '1');

  // I used here constant placeholders, for line numbering
  // margin it's the MARGIN_LINE_NUMBERS and for code folding
  // margin it's the MARGIN_CODE_FOLDING constant

  DScintilla1.SetMarginWidthN(MARGIN_CODE_FOLDING, 0);
  DScintilla1.SetMarginTypeN(MARGIN_CODE_FOLDING, SC_MARGIN_SYMBOL);
  DScintilla1.SetMarginMaskN(MARGIN_CODE_FOLDING, SC_MASK_FOLDERS);
  DScintilla1.SetMarginWidthN(MARGIN_LINE_NUMBERS, 40);
  DScintilla1.SetMarginWidthN(MARGIN_CODE_FOLDING, 20);

  // markers for code folding

  DScintilla1.MarkerDefine(SC_MARKNUM_FOLDER, SC_MARK_PLUS);
  DScintilla1.MarkerDefine(SC_MARKNUM_FOLDEROPEN, SC_MARK_MINUS);
  DScintilla1.MarkerDefine(SC_MARKNUM_FOLDEREND, SC_MARK_EMPTY);
  DScintilla1.MarkerDefine(SC_MARKNUM_FOLDERMIDTAIL, SC_MARK_EMPTY);
  DScintilla1.MarkerDefine(SC_MARKNUM_FOLDEROPENMID, SC_MARK_EMPTY);
  DScintilla1.MarkerDefine(SC_MARKNUM_FOLDERSUB, SC_MARK_EMPTY);
  DScintilla1.MarkerDefine(SC_MARKNUM_FOLDERTAIL, SC_MARK_EMPTY);

  // also very important, this will enable the OnMarginClick event
  // to fire, if you set the ASensitive parameter to False or omit
  // this line, the OnMarginClick will never fire

  DScintilla1.SetMarginSensitiveN(MARGIN_CODE_FOLDING, True);

  // and some visual settings

  SetColors(SCE_H_DEFAULT, clBlack);
  SetColors(SCE_H_TAG, clPurple, clWindow, True);
  SetColors(SCE_H_TAGUNKNOWN, clRed);
  SetColors(SCE_H_ATTRIBUTE, clNavy);
  SetColors(SCE_H_ATTRIBUTEUNKNOWN, clRed);
  SetColors(SCE_H_NUMBER, clBlue);
  SetColors(SCE_H_DOUBLESTRING, clBlue);
  SetColors(SCE_H_SINGLESTRING, clBlue);
  SetColors(SCE_H_OTHER, clBlack);
  SetColors(SCE_H_COMMENT, clTeal);
  SetColors(SCE_H_ENTITY, clPurple);
  SetColors(SCE_H_TAGEND, clPurple);
  SetColors(SCE_H_CDATA, clTeal);
end;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks, i will try it this afternoon and come back with the results